# Unable to pass data from AppCompatDialogFragment to Fragment (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fragment

I am trying to pass Cloud Firestore data from my alert dialog to fragment. Firestore data is stored as list view. I am able to read Firestore data when I click item inside my List View but unable to pass it to my fragment via interface.

What I've tried:

I've tried to make classic communication between two fragment (Alert Dialog Fragment and Fragment).
I want to pass data from ListView to fragment using interface.

What kind of erros I am facing:
I'm currently facing  "Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference"

My Code :

```
   private SendData listener;

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //   System.out.println(arrayList.get(position));

            String item_name = arrayList.get(position);

            db.collection("FoodName").document(item_name).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

                             String calories =  documentSnapshot.getString(CALORIES);
                             listener.ApplyData(calories);
                        }
                    });

public interface SendData
 {
     void ApplyData (String calories);
 }


@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
         listener = (SendData) context;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        System.out.println("onAttach: ClassCastException : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Full Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smartmove, PID: 25860
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.smartmove.AlertDialogFoodList$SendData.ApplyData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.smartmove.AlertDialogFoodList$2$1.onSuccess(AlertDialogFoodList.java:109)
        at com.example.smartmove.AlertDialogFoodList$2$1.onSuccess(AlertDialogFoodList.java:103)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Register listener through Dialog Fragment constructor instead of onAttach(...). In your case it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the listener after creating the AlertDialog.

```
mDialog.setListener(this);
```

In your AlterDialog class,

```
public void setListener(SendData listener){
   this.listener = listener;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So When you expect communication between Fragment and DialogFragment, ideal way is to set target Fragment. This way you can pass response from DialogFragment to Fragment. Check the code below:

Your interface:

```
public interface SendData
{
     void ApplyData (String calories);
}
```

**Your Fragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements SendData {

    private void showDialogFragment() {
        DialogFragment dialogFrag = MainDialogFragment();
        dialogFrag.setTargetFragment(this, 123);
        dialogFrag.show(getFragmentManager, "MainDialogFragment");
    }

    @override
    public void ApplyData(String calories){

    }
}
```

**Your DialogFragment:**

```
public class MyialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private SendData sendData;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Fragment fragment = getTargetFragment();
        if (fragment instanceof SendData) {
            sendData = (SendData) fragment;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Target Fragment is not implementing SendData interface");
        }
    }
}
```

This should work!